# Spring protruding from office chair?

Tags: repair, upholstery

I've had this chair for a few months and the other day I came around to get on the computer and noticed a decently sized lump in the chair.

[image]
Upon sitting on the chair it feels springy on parts (which left me to believe this is a spring bulging out) but rock hard on others. I don't want to mess with it too much without knowing what I'm even dealing with. Any advice on what it could be or what I should do to get it resolved?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Unfortunately, furniture repair is off-topic here. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about furniture repair.

Comment: To be fair, there's other questions about furniture repair, so I figured it was fine

Comment: It is probably time to buy a new chair